# Raspberry Pi won't boot up after installing Adafruit's Jessie PiTFT image

Tags: raspbian-jessie, boot-issues, touchscreen, pitft, troubleshooting

I am trying to have my Raspberry Pi 3 work with an Adafruit TFT.  I installed their Jessie based image (http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install), and now my Pi freezes part way through the booting (all of the steps say OK though, and the last line just says "mounted /boot," which doesn't look like an error to me).

It worked with Jessie installed through NOOBS before I downloaded the Adafruit version, so I don't think that it is the SD card that is the issue.

Various questions suggested that the issue might be that it is switching from the TV screen (via HDMI) to the TFT partway through boot-up, however I get the same issues with just the TV plugged in and with both, plus the TFT doesn't work at all.

When I'm looking at the files on the SD card, there is just a boot partition, but there was a recovery partition before the update (I don't know if this is relevant though).

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?  Did I screw up downloading the image?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this version of Jesse is defective.  It is meant to work with the resistive touchscreen created by Aafruit but it doesn't seem to.  Can't find a solution anywhere.  Seems like you have to go back to a previous version of Raspbian and manually install the script by Adafruit so you can get the touchscreen to work and the pi to run.  This process is very time consuming and I am not sure if Adafruit is aware of the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you buy the smallest Micro SD you can (4GB if possible) and burn the standard Raspbian image to it. Run the updates, customise the login, add the TFT then back that card up to a PC using Win32diskimager.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try rewriting the image

or

try it using a different SD card